# Simplifying Hibernate's Query

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have the following code which perfroms a simple query from a single table of an Oracle database.

```
entityManager.createQuery(
        "SELECT a FROM " + Person.class.getSimpleName() 
        + " a WHERE lower(a.firstName) = '" + firstName + "'")
        .getSingleResult();
```

Hibernate produces the following sql:

```
select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            person0_.id as id75_,
            person0_.FIRSTNAME as FIRSTNAME75_,
            person0_.LASTNAME as LASTNAME75_
        from
            PERSONS person0_ 
        where
            lower(person0_.FIRSTNAME)='john' ) 
    where
        rownum <= ?
```

Our DBA suggests that this query should be simpler for performance reasons. How can I make hibernate to simplify the query
like this:

```
select ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME from PERSONS 
where lower(FIRSTNAEM) = 'john' and rownum <= 1
```

Thanks

Comment: first of all I would create an index on the field FIRSTNAME.

Comment: @StefanBe: and that index would be ignored as the where clause is using a function.  You'd need a functional index...

Comment: ah ok. dont know that

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In short - you don't. There is almost never a good enough reason to tweak the queries that Hibernate generates, and I have seroius doubts that it is possible without modifying the source code.

The only simplification I can think of is to call `getResultList().get(0)` instead of `getSingleResult()`. It would simplify the generated SQL a bit, but will result in a performance hit, not an improvement, since you will be fetching all matching rows from DB.

You could however improve the query a bit.

You know the simple name of the class you are querying for. There is no need to get it from the Entity first and concatenate, simply use

`SELECT a FROM Person a...`

Concatenating parameters for a query is not a good practice. It  makes your query vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. It is better to write:

```
...WHERE lower(a.firstName) = :firstName");
query.setParameter("firstName", firstName);
```

Comment: I think calling `getResultList().get(0)` is a bad idea as you would then return all the rows from the database only for your code to just use the first row.  It'll be better performance to let Oracle only return a single row.

Comment: @beny23 yes, definitely, it will worsen the performance, but it will simplify the query a bit. I have made it more explicit in the answer now, it was not really clear.

Comment: What if getResultList() is expected to return 1 row by using a unique field in the where clause?

Comment: @RueLeonheart - I am not sure if the DB will be intelligent enough to stop after the first match, as it will on `getSingleResult`. It will probably still be a bit less efficient as there is more work to be done - creating the list etc.

Answer (score 8):

I've just looked at the `explain plan` for queries similar to yours and the plan is exactly the same for both queries, so I'm not sure what performance reasons your DBA is suggesting.

Wrapping the query with `select * from ( ... ) where rownum = 1` introduces a STOPKEY that stops the inner query after one row.  Oracle knows that you do not actually want to get all results from the subquery and then only take the first row.

Changing the query produced by Hibernate is going to be impossible without modifying the hibernate source code itself.

Note, the reason why this nesting is necessary becomes obvious when you try to introduce an `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME 
  from PERSONS 
 where lower(FIRSTNAME) = 'john' 
   and rownum <= 1
 order by LASTNAME
```

produces different results to

```
select * from (
    select ID, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME 
      from PERSONS 
     where lower(FIRSTNAME) = 'john' 
     order by LASTNAME)
  where rownum <= 1
```

as the `where rownum` is applied before the `order by clause`....

EDIT:

For reference here's the output of the explain plan, and that's exactly the same for both queries:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation          | Name       | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT   |            |     1 |   112 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY     |            |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL| TABLE_NAME |     1 |   112 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The performance can be improved by putting a functional index on `lower(FIRST_NAME)` but that would be used by both queries exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest, that you use query parameters:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT a FROM "
    + Person.class.getSimpleName() 
    + " a WHERE lower(a.firstName) = :name");
query.setParameter("name", firstName);
return query.getSingleResult();
```

This has two important reasons:

- You protect against SQL-injection
- You allow SQL-server to cache parsed query improving consequent executions performance

Considering

```
select * from (...) where rownum <= ?
```

wrapper: this costs no performance at all. You can just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised, no one suggested rewriting as native Query instead of sticking to what Hibernate generates. I had the same issue, though mine has nothing to do with performance but the result of the Query was never the same, infact the Query was hard to understand.

The best way to go for short and long term reasons is to take control of the Query, use Native Query anywhere, anytime possible. 
Simply write the Query as your DBA suggested and put it in as JPQL NamedNativeQuery, and everyone is happy. Enjoy!